# difference between two highlighted values

Tags: vba

i hava a column B which has time values. Ther are some values which are highlighted in blue. Is there chance to find difference between those highlighted values in that colum thru vba.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is how you can check the background color of a cell:

```
MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("j23").Interior.Color
```

and this is how you check cell's value:

```
MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("j23").value
```

Comment: This is good but can i just select all the blue highlighted rows and find their differences in values. (like b1-b4 and b8-b4)

Comment: Could you make the question a bit more precise, please? If I understand you correctly, you can define a range, run a 'foreach' loop for all cells within that range, if a particular cell is blue put its value to some array. And then you can do some actions using these values.